# Why did Iran not stop the implementation of the agreement?

Tags: united-states, iran

Since the seizure of nearly two billion dollars in [Iranian assets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_frozen_assets) by United States.

> Almost $1.973 billion of Iran's assets are frozen in the United States

Why did Iran not stop the implementation of the agreement?

Comment: What "agreement" are you talking about specifically? Iran is party to quite a lot of different agreements.

Comment: @Philipp - the context (2016 seizure) seems to make it nearly crystal clear that [NDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_nuclear_deal_framework) was meant